# apiRTC Android application crashes when creating video stream twice

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am developping a video conference application around apiRTC and I have an activity which allows the user previewing his camera before starting a video call. For this purpose, I use a SurfaceViewRenderer and I pretty much use the code given in the samples to initiate this preview

```
public void setLocalVideoView(@NonNull SurfaceViewRenderer videoView) {
        if (mLocalVideoView != null) {
            mLocalVideoView.release();
        }
        mLocalVideoView = videoView;
        mLocalVideoView.init(getSharedVideoContext(), null);
        mLocalVideoView.setScalingType(RendererCommon.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FIT);
        mLocalVideoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
        mLocalVideoView.setEnableHardwareScaler(true);
        mLocalVideoView.setMirror(false);
        createLocalStream();
    }

    /**
     * Creates the local camera stream.
     */
    protected void createLocalStream() {
        if (mSelectedCamera != null && mLocalVideoView != null) {
            final UserAgent.CreateStreamOptions createStreamOptions = new UserAgent.CreateStreamOptions();
            createStreamOptions.component2().setAudio(true);
            createStreamOptions.component2().setVideo(true);
            createStreamOptions.setVideoInputId(mSelectedCamera.getId());
            mUserAgent.createStream(createStreamOptions).then(this::onLocalStreamCreated, this::onLocalStreamCreationFailed);
        }
    }
```

The problem is : if I leave this activity and go there again, the application crashes.

UserAgent.createStream triggers the error callback but I get an exception at the same time :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void org.webrtc.CapturerObserver.onCapturerStarted(boolean)' on a null object reference
at org.webrtc.CameraCapturer$1.onDone(CameraCapturer.java:46)
at org.webrtc.Camera2Session$CaptureSessionCallback.onConfigured(Camera2Session.java:211)
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CallbackProxies$SessionStateCallbackProxy.lambda$onConfigured$0$CallbackProxies$SessionStateCallbackProxy(CallbackProxies.java:53)
```

My guess is that the camera is not properly released but I don't know what I am missing. I have release calls in the onDestroy method of my activity

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to release the localstream in the onDestroy method like this is done on apiRTC Android SDK tuto?

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    toast(ToastyType.TOASTY_INFO, "Call terminated")

    localStream?.release()

    ua?.unregister()
    localVideoView?.release()

    for ((stream, _) in usedSurfaceViewRenderer) {
        putBackSurfaceViewRenderer(stream)
    }

    audioTerminate()

    connectedConversation = null

    super.onDestroy()
}
```